# Give column alias from attribute

Tags: sql-server

i want query to give column alias from attribute, I tried this but didn't worked

```
$
  declare @e varchar
    set @e = 'try'

    SELECT     dbo.Mn.id, dbo.Mn.name,DCF.asd as @e
    FROM         dbo.DCF INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Mn ON dbo.DCF.id = dbo.Mn.id   

$
```

Comment: BTW, you are declaring a variable not an attribute

Comment: In short, you can't. You need dynamic SQL to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using dynamic SQL if you want to use the value of a variable as an alias:

```
declare @e nvarchar(10)
set @e = N'try'

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 
    'SELECT     dbo.Mn.id, dbo.Mn.name,DCF.asd as ' + @e +
    ' FROM         dbo.DCF INNER JOIN
            dbo.Mn ON dbo.DCF.id = dbo.Mn.id'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

---

As an aside, always specify the length of string types, e.g. `varchar(10)` instead of `varchar`. If you use just `varchar` when declaring a variable, SQL Server makes it `varchar(1)` which is not what you expected.